# How to Get a image file type using GDI+ in c++?

Tags: image, file, gdi+, types

Some jpeg image is stored with .bmp ext.
I want to use gdi+ to get the real type of the image file, how can I do this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a C# version (using the System.Drawing.Imaging namespace):

```
    public static ImageFormat getImageFileFormat( string filename )
    {
        using ( var fs = new System.IO.FileStream( filename, System.IO.FileMode.Open ) )
        using ( var img = Image.FromStream( fs, true, false ) )
            return img.RawFormat;
    }
```

With this function, you can do something like:

```
    ImageFormat fmt = getImageFileFormat( @"some file" );
    if ( fmt.Guid == ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid )
    {
      ...
    }
    else if ( fmt.Guid == ImageFormat.Bmp.Guid )
    {
      ...
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now I know how to do it in c++.